# Backgrounds Color For Primary Menu and Secondry Menu

Tags: user-behavior, design-patterns, user-expectation, dashboard, contextual-menu

I am designing the statistics tools which will have it's ***Dashboard filled with multiple floating tiles*** **showing accurate data as per user's need.**

Apart from that we have ***primary and secondary menu***,

Now, I need an advice about which type of **treatment** both the background can have **in terms of colors** so that they can **stand out** with their **own importance**, ***making sure that the dashboard tiles are highlighted more.***'

Make sure it has to be only colors, not patterns or any shiny things needed. Just the color. A link will also help a lot.

Comment: Are you asking everyone to suggest a colour palette at random?

Comment: Obviously not but suggestion in terms of what works well with an appropriate example of link or reference, why on earth will I ask for color palette!?

Comment: @R.Rajpara You may need to reword the question then because asking for advice about the background in terms of colors, sounds like you're asking for examples of which colors you should use, i.e. a color palette

Comment: @R.Rajpara, both your question and your comment are LITERALLY asking for color palettes, please edit your question if you want answers

Comment: Thanks @Devin for your suggestion, I see I already got an answer without me changing my question. 

In fact the problem at my end is solved as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To start with I recommend you use colour combinations with high levels of contrast.
  [http://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/](http://webaim%20contrast%20checker)
- You can also play with the alpha opacity (CSS3) to distinguish between hierarchy with the more opaque element being the most prominent.
  Primary:    `background-color: rgba(203, 244, 203, 1);`
  Secondary:  `background-color: rgba(203, 244, 203, 0.6);`
- Or you may want to style the tiles so they are noticeably different from their siblings. I tend to add a box-shadow [box shadow generator](http://box-shadow%20generator) but it's up to your taste.

Comment: Thanks for discussing your suggestions with me :) It was help full to get my head straight.

Comment: You're welcome! Thanks for the opportunity to "answer" something rather than my usual browsing :)